# How to paste images like this on EditText,Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image: screenshot from note 4,note 4 memo app]

Hi,

I am making a memo app for learning android. actually, I made one app that can save Texts only into Sqlite.
now I want to modify my app like the screenshot that the editText can have images and texts.

So here are 2 questions.

- How to paste images into the app I made ? ( Currently that allows text paste.)
- This is I am still thinking of DB structure that How to save Images with some texts ? ( I tested saving images only into DB using BitmapFactory & BLOB)

Thank you.

My app editText XML is :

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addBtn"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

What I want to do is :

This is from memo app of my note4 that I want like this.  Any images i want to copy ,then long-touch it to copy and paste it into the app.
[image: Example]

Comment: 1) what did you try about your custom EditText?
2) you can save in sqlite the path

Comment: @VassilisPallas Hi:) I added my app's editText XML that only can contains Text. If you are fine, Could you give me any reference for the 2nd question ? I want to have a read :) Thank you.

Comment: one easy way is to play with Html.fromHtml() and Html.ImageGetter (the second is interface)

Comment: Thank you. But that is not what I want :(

Comment: By paste what do you mean? If you mean real copy (to save it in clipboard), as far as I know this is impossible. The only way to copy or cut a file is to write it again in other destination. Now if tou want just to add it in your edittext the interface will do the job (with some code of course).

Comment: Vassilis , really thanks for your prompt reply. I just added one example screenshot. :)